# How to Save "Data.Json" file from assets to internal Storage and then use it for read/write

Tags: java, android

Currently i am fetching a package details(Onnet Minutes, Offnet Minutes, etc) from a Json file "**Data.json**" from **assets** but i know we cannot change values from assets. So my Question is how to copy **Data.json** to **internal storage** and then Load it for read/Write.

I am using this to load Data.Json from Assets

```
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("Data.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        Toast.makeText(jazz_sim_lagao_offer_details.this, "JSON Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

and using this code to update data

```
    private void UpdateData() {
    JSONObject JSONobj = null;
    try {
        loadJSONFromAsset();
        //get JSONObject from JSON file
        JSONobj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        //fetch JSONObject named
        JSONObject Jazz_SimLagaoOffer = JSONobj.getJSONObject("packages").getJSONObject("jazz_packages").getJSONObject("call_packages").getJSONObject("sim_lagao_offer");



        String Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_ONNET = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("onnet");
        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_OnNet_TextView.setText(Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_ONNET);

        String Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_OFFNET = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("offnet");
        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_OffNet_TextView.setText(Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_OFFNET);

        String Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_MBs = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("mbs");
        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_Mb_TextView.setText(Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_MBs);

        String Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_SMS = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("sms");
        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_Sms_TextView.setText(Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_SMS);


        String Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_SUBCODE = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("sub_code");
        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_Sub_Code_TextView.setText(Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_SUBCODE);


        String Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_CHECKCODE = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("check_code");
        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_Check_Code_TextView.setText(Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_CHECKCODE);

        String Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_UNSUBCODE = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("unsub_code");
        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_Unsub_Code_TextView.setText(Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_UNSUBCODE);

        Jazz_SimLagaoOffer_Charges = Jazz_SimLagaoOffer.getString("charges");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), JSONobj + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

How to Get Json Object?

Here is My **Data.Json**

```html
{
  "packages" : {
    "jazz_packages" : {
      "call_packages" : {
        "sim_lagao_offer" : {
          "charges" : "0.01",
          "check_code" : "*551*2#",
          "mbs" : "1500",
          "offnet" : "5000",
          "onnet" : "3000",
          "sms" : "3000",
          "sub_code" : "*551#",
          "unsub_code" : "*551*3#"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void CopyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;



        System.out.println("File name => "+filename);
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(YOUR_ASSETS_FILE);   // if files resides inside the "Files" directory itself
            out = new FileOutputStream(STORAGE_PATH).toString() +"/" + filename);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Use below code to read from storage

```
    String jsongString = readFromFile();
    JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsongString);
    JSONObject Jazz_SimLagaoOffer = mainJsonObject.getJSONObject("packages").getJSONObject("jazz_packages").getJSONObject("call_packages").getJSONObject("sim_lagao_offer");
```

Use below method to read data from internal storage file and return as String.

```
private String readFromFile() {

String ret = "";
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = openFileInput("names.json");

    if ( inputStream != null ) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String receiveString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
        }

        ret = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
}
finally {
  try {
     inputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

return ret;
```

}

Hope this work :)

Comment: thats right ! but how to Load that as i loaded from assets

Comment: @H2Five please check my edited answer, added function to load data from storage

Comment: i need to load json Object i edited my question please check and guide me to get json object from copied "Data.json" file

Comment: @H2Five could you please show how is your json and from that which one object you want to get?

Comment: Question is Updated

Comment: @H2Five check new answer JSONArray replaced with JSONObject. Now if your json file loaded successfully than your complete Json is in "mainJsonObject". after all  you are doing correct. if you get any error, let me know with your error

Comment: cannot resolve  symbol "str" from this line  >> JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject(str);

Comment: replace "str" with "jsongString"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207455/discussion-between-h2five-and-pratik-vekariya).

Comment: Your CopyAssets() works perfect but readFromFile() does not work in my case so i updated with an answer, Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I Got Answer my own Question after 1 Day Research and Thanks to @pratik vekariya
helped me a lot.

CopyAssets() works perfect as defined @pratik vekariya in his answer and to readfromfile see my Question loadJSONFromAssets() 
and i Just replaced line

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("Data.json");
```

with this

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir().toString() +"/" + "Data.json");
```

to to load .json file from **files** and get json object from inputStrem